# Two attributes sharing the same OneToMany relationship to one entity Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many, many-to-one

Let's first describe my situation. I am using Symfony2 and I have a problem with a relationship between my entities.

I have two entities that are linked together. The two entities are `AssociationQuestion` and `AssociationPossibleAnswer`. I am currently creating a questionary software where one would have to link one possible answer on the left to another one possible answer on the right, such as in the following example:

[image]

Currently, I'm planning on having two attributes that are arrays in class `AssociationQuestion` that would hold many `AssociationPossibleAnswer` objects. The first array would contain the possible answers on the left and the second one would contain the possible answers on the right.

Therefore, to me, it looks like I would have two oneToMany relations in `AssociationQuestion`

```
AssociationQuestion:

    oneToMany:
        possibleAnswersLeft:
            targetEntity: AssociationPossibleAnswer
            mappedBy: associationQuestion

        possibleAnswersRight:
            targetEntity: AssociationPossibleAnswer
            mappedBy: associationQuestion
```

Then, in `AssociationPossibleAnswer`, I would have one ManyToOne relation :

```
AssociationPossibleAnswer:
    manyToOne:
        associationQuestion:
            targetEntity: AssociationQuestion
```

The problem is that I get the following error trying to validate my doctrine. It seems that you can't have two entities linked to one as I would wish to do...

```
* The field AssociationQuestion#possibleAnswersLeft is on the inverse side of a bi-directional relationship, but the specified mappedBy association on the target-entity AssociationPossibleAnswer#associationQuestion does not contain the required 'inversedBy=possibleAnswersLeft' attribute.

* The field AssociationQuestion#possibleAnswersRight is on the inverse side of a bi-directional relationship, but the specified mappedBy association on the target-entity AssociationPossibleAnswer#associationQuestion does not contain the required 'inversedBy=possibleAnswersRight' attribute.
```

I'm wondering if this is the proper way to set my relation between my two entities. **Is it possible to have two attributes pointing to an entity while in return the entity does not know which attribute it is being pointed from.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This case cannot be solved with OneToMany associations.

You need 2 distinct relations between `AssociationQuestion` and `AssociationPossibleAnswer`. The way you've set it up, you only have 1 relation. Just look at the 1 ManyToOne association you created in `AssociationPossibleAnswer`.

And you're trying to have 2 opposite sides of that 1 relation, which is theoretically impossible. A relation can only have 2 endpoints (not 3).

**Solution**

Implement 2 (unidirectional) ManyToMany associations in `AssociationQuestion`, and make the foreign key pointing to `AssociationPossibleAnswer` unique:

```
class AssociationQuestion
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AssociationPossibleAnswer")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="association_question_association_possible_answer_left",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="association_question_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="association_possible_answer_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     * )
     */
    private $possibleAnswersLeft;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AssociationPossibleAnswer")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="association_question_association_possible_answer_right",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="association_question_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="association_possible_answer_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     * )
     */
    private $possibleAnswersRight;

    // ...
```

Doctrine calls this a [One-To-Many, Unidirectional with Join Table](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table) association.